# UIScrollView with images - how not to zoom one of them

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

I've got a lot of `imageViews` in `scrollView`. The problem is that i want one of them NOT to have its image zoomed in. I can't move the `imageView` one outside of `scrollView`, because it has to change place(frame) according to zoom and pan gestures in `scrollView`. Is there any chance not to zoom the image of this `imageView`?

Comment: Dynamically and consistently update its zoom to be `1/zoomGestureZoom`?

Comment: @JamesWebster What do you mean exactly..? I can't change zoom of imageView, can change only the zoom of scrollView. I don't want to change zoom of scrollView because there are other imageViews that should be zoomed.

Comment: Ah, ignore that. I don't use UIKit very much, I didn't realised scaling a UIImageView was non-trivial.

Comment: What is the size of imageviews that you add in the scrollview? are the imageViews smaller in size to that of the view of scrollView or equal to the size of it ?

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 The imageViews have different sizes and transformations. Some are equal, some are bigger, some are smaller. The one i don't want to zoom in its content image is equal in width or height with the scrollView and smaller in opposite direction. Also this one have no transformations.

Comment: @Vive : check my answer. 1st 6 lines of code are not getting converted to code-view here in the answer so read it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you imageViews are of different size in regards to the size of the scrollview holding them, you can achieve this will the following

1. Derive a class from UIScrollView and add UIImageView within it. Like below:

   ```
   @interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
   @property(nonatomic,retain)UIImageView *imageView;
   @end

   @implementation

   -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
   {
       self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
       {

           self.delegate = self;
           self.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
           self.maximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
           self.bounces= NO;

           self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
           [self addSubview:self.imageView];
       }

       return self;
   }

   -(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
   {
       return self.imageView;
   }

   @end
   ```
2. Now you can add the instances of the above MyScrollView to you actual scrollView. 
   This will be like scrollViews in a scrollView.
3. Make your holding scrollView non-zoomable.
4. Add your images in each scrollView by following:

   [myScrollViewInstance.imageView setImage:myImage];

This way on performing pinch gestures, only the imageView underneath you pinch will zoom-in or zoom out.